# Android studio - Auto complete doesn't work

Tags: android-studio, autocomplete

I'm just learning Android studio and everything worked fine until couple of days ago. It's missing some fundamental auto complete suggestions, and sometimes none are present. There also seems to be missing a lot of view attributes in the designer, under the All attributes tab. Every time I test if suggestions works, I wait for all the indexing and other stuff to finish before trying.

[Example of new project with no suggestions on XML editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N0Ti.jpg)

[Same project with limited suggestions on the most basic thing, does not suggest android:id at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzoia.jpg)

I've tried just about anything I could find with google and nothing works.

- Power saver is off, and I've tried to turn it on and off. No affect
- I've tried "file > invalidate caches / restart" multiple times, no affect.
- I've deleted cache-folders and all those other folders too that has been suggested, many times. No affect.
- I've gone through the settings with a fine comb to find any setting that could affect this, but haven't found anything wrong.
- I've completely uninstalled Android studio, and deleted all related folders. I deleted all registry entries even remotely connected to it. After re-install (no imported settings), problem persists.
- I've tried cleaning and rebuilding my project. No affect.
- Copying all the sources and resources to a new project won't help because this happens even if I start a new project and try to type in it. No suggestions, or at most, very limited suggestions.

I'm thinking of completely wiping my computer and re-installing everything, but I'd rather not, because it's a huge task and a pain in the ass.

Sometimes when typing I accidentally hit a random hotkey that opens something, and usually I just hit esc to continue my work, but I'm afraid I accidentally hit something to cause this. But I cannot undestand how can it still be broken after complete uninstall and re-install?

I'm using Android studio Arctic fox 2020.3.1. Patch 3, because the tutorials I'm using are based on that version, and in the past I've made the mistake to update the software and none of the tutorial code work anymore. This has also been a huge pain to get everything working again, but somehow I've done it. Now I'd like to get this thing to work again. Any ideas?

Edit. Oh, right. I have Android studio installed on my laptop as well, so I've been comparing between the two computers so that I know I'm not crazy :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've tried so many things after posting the question, and I found a solution. It's not what I wanted, but now it works.

So I completely uninstalled Android studio (for the thousandth time) and upgraded to Arctic fox patch 4. No luck.

Then I completely uninstalled it and downgraded to um.. some stable version previous to Arctic fox. No luck.

Then I uninstalled and upgraded to latest Chipmunk and it EFFING FORKED!

Now in the hopes that whatever was broken was fixed, I tried to downgrade back to Arctic fox so that I could get back to my tutorials, but no luck there, so I upgraded back to Chipmunk and I guess I just need to work myself through all the changes they've made that make all the tutorial code not functioning. Maybe I'll learn a thing or two on the way.